# how can I update my datatable with my hidden column ? codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

i want to update a row using my hidden column compared with my id . I hashed my id and stored my hash into a table. I want to do something similar update table set row where md5(id) = hash then update.. I got this so far. how can I fix it?

controller

```
public function updateProduct(){
        $descripcion = $this->input->post('description');
        $cost_price =  $this->input->post('cost_price');
        $selling_price = $this->input->post('selling_price');
        $wprice = $this->input->post('wprice');
        $min_stock = $this->input->post('min_stock');
        $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
        $max_stock = $this->input->post('max_stock');
        $data = array(
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'precio_compra' => $cost_price,
            'precio_venta' => $selling_price,
            'precio_mayoreo' => $wprice,
            'existencia_minima' => $min_stock,
            'existencia' => $stock,
            'existencia_maxima' => $max_stock
        );
        if ($data['existencia'] > $data['existencia_minima']) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'));
        }elseif ($data['existencia_maxima'] < $data['existencia']) {
            $this->json(array('max_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al max'));
        }else{
           $this->products->updateProduct($data);
            $this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
           $this->json($data);
        }
    }
```

model

```
public function updateProduct($data){
        $this->db->update('storelte_articulos',$data);
        $this->db->where('md5(id)',$this->input->post('id'));
    }
```

datatable

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthChange": false,
    responsive: true,
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [{
         extend: 'excelHtml5',
         exportOptions:{
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
         }
    },{
        extend: 'csvHtml5',
        exportOptions:{
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        }
    },{
        extend: 'pdf',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        }
    }],
    ajax: {
        url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
        type: 'POST',
    },
    columnDefs:[{
        targets: -1,
        data: null,
        defaultContent: "<a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>"

    },{
        targets: 7,
        render: function (data) {
            return (data == 1) ? "<span class='label label-success'>active</span>":"<span class='label label-danger'>inactive</span>";
        }
    },
    {
        targets: 0,
        visible: false,
        render: function (data) {
           return  '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+data+'" >';
        }
    }],
    fnRowCallback: function (data,nRow) {
        if (nRow[7] == 0) {
            $(data).css({'background-color':'#f2dede'});
        }else if(nRow[7] == 1){
            $(data).css({'background-color':'#dff0d8'});
        }else{

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where you find this $this->db->where('md5(id)',$this->input->post('id'));

Comment: ```public function updateProduct($data)
{
 $this->db->update('storelte_articulos', $data, array('md5(id)' => $this->input->post('id')));
}```

Comment: I tried, but it wont work